# Tikz graph error

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to plot the curve of

```
\frac{1}{x - 1}
```

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,
footskip=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red] (0,0) plot [domain=0.5:4] (\x,1/(\x-1));
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This throws an error.

If I write this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red] (0,0) plot [domain=0.5:4] (\x,1/x);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It's fine. It can handle this.

The error message is:

Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?. ... plot [domain=0.5:4] (\x,1/(\x-1))

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Please give us a MWE  : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is the double brackets. You should put the expression within `{}`. And then have the (x-1) within the brackets so the eventual `\begin{tikzpicture}` input should look like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red] (0,0) plot [domain=0.5:4] (\x, {1/(\x-1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```